# SQL Server 2019 Express - can create table but unable to insert records

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-insert

It seems I have installed 2019 Express and SSMS correctly.

Using SSMS, I have created a user and schema by the same name, and made this the default schema for this user (who is the owner).

I can connect to the server using ODBC, and successfully create a simple table using:

```
CREATE TABLE Jobs ( RowID integer primary key, JobCode Char(7) not null default ' ', ClientCode Char(10) not null default ' ', JobName Char(70) not null default ' ', AddrRowID Integer default 0 )
```

The program then successfully sends the following command (again via ODBC):

```
grant alter, select, update, insert, delete on Jobs to UserID
```

However, the server returns an error, when the program sends the following command (via ODBC):

```
INSERT INTO Jobs ( JobCode, ClientCode, JobName ) VALUES ( '  A2', 'ADDRE50000', 'Client data entry (new records & editing)' );
```

I can't figure out what is wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI it's back ticks (`\``) you want for code fences, not single quotes (`'`). Also, I really recommend starting to make good use of line breaks and white space early on when writing code. Single long lines of code are notoriously hard to read and debug.

Comment: Alsoz if you're getting an error, don't forget to tell us what that error is I your question.

Comment: You will likelly regret the use of character codes as fixed-length strings and the attempt to format them with spaces. A default value of ' ' (one space) likely means the same as "not provided" - which is something that NULL is typically used for. And you have no foreign keys but it seems you should - ClientCode should probably be a FK to a Client table (which is where those spacey default will cause problems). Most likely JobName should be unique. In short, designing a "good" database is a very different skill from writing tsql queries.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive suggestions Larnu  & SMor. Pointers like this are valuable for becoming a better programmer - and StackOverflow participator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change table creation query
Add IDENTITY for RowID column

```
RowID integer primary key IDENTITY
```

or add this column to insert query

```
INSERT INTO Jobs ( RowID ,JobCode, ClientCode, JobName ) VALUES ( {yourId},' A2', 'ADDRE50000', 'Client data entry (new records & editing)' );
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Adding IDENTITY into the CREATE TABLE seems the better approach, and worked perfectly !!!